# Visual studio 2015 - Web Compiler not working with nested less files and variable-files

Tags: c#, less, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials, web-compiler

My project has used Web Essentials for compiling our styling .less files in visual studio 2013.
With the upgrad to VS2015 and further an update to Web Essentials 2015 we learned that web essentials 2015 does not support compiling of less files ([link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee6e6d8c-c837-41fb-886a-6b50ae2d06a2))

We must therefore use grunt or web compiler to compile less files. Neither looks as smooth as web essentials.

I tried Web Compiler, but it seem to not work with our nested files and therefore it gets errors on our styling variables.

```
   // Bootstrap
  // ---------------------------------------------
   @import "bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
   @import "bootstrap/less/responsive.less";

    @import "bootstrap/less/variables.less";
```

And some errors:

```
Error       (WebCompiler) NameError: variable @inputHeight is undefined in \Content\bootstrap\less\mixins.less  MyProject.Web   

Error       NameError: .tab-focus is undefined in \Content\bootstrap\less\reset.less    MyProject.Web
```

does anyone know how to fix this with Web Compiler?
if not, does grunt or 'Bundler & Minifier' work better?

Answer (score 0):

Looked like it was not Web compiler who was the direct problem. Web compiler had issues compiling and old version of bootstrap (v. 2.3.2).
Solved when changing some lines in the bootstrap file.